# Android Studio не компилирует актуальную версию приложения

Tags: android, android-studio

Столкнулся с проблемой того, что Андроид Студио перестал компилировать актуальную версию приложения. Компилирует он одну и ту же старую версию, какие бы изменения я в нее не вносил.

Помогите, пожалуйста, даже не представляю, в чем проблема. Если нужна какая-то доп. информация, предоставлю (просто не представляю, что может пригодиться). Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте в меню AS `Build->Clean Project`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При любых необъяснимых проблемах пробуем две кнопки "сделать все хорошо":

1. Build -> Clean project
2. File -> Invalidate Cфches / Restart -> Invalidate Caches and Restart

Готов поставить что-нибудь на то, что ваша проблема одной из этих кнопок решится

Comment: Cпасибо за помощь, если что, буду знать :) На самом деле, как оказалось, никакой такой проблемы не было, в коде накосячил и чего-то ждал, измучал Gradle уже :)